# Creating from blank canvas sharepoint lookup fields are not visible when editing form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerapps

Creating from blank Powerapp canvas Sharepoint lookup fields are not visible when editing form.

It is working fine if I start creating my app from Sharepoint data however I need tablet/web layout. I am using on-prem Sharepoint data and a gateway.

**Update:** As a workaround I was able to convert my phone layout app derived from sharepoint list to a tablet layout by saving to local folder and updating the properties json file.

Steps:

1. Save phone layout app created from sharepoint data to local folder.
2. Create a blank app from tablet layout and save to local folder.
3. Rename both .msapp files by adding the .zip extension.
4. Extract both file to one directory
5. open the properties.json file of both apps and update the LocalConnectionReferences, DocumentLayoutWidth, DocumentLayoutHeight, DocumentLayoutOrientation, DocumentAppType to be the same as the value of the blank app
6. Save and drag updated properties.json to the original zip file.
7. Rename from zip to msapp extension.
8. Reopen from powerapps, browse from local folder.
9. Click App Settings.Click Screen size + orientation.
10. In the Size radio button, select 3:2. Click Apply.Click Save.
11. In the Size radio button, select 16:9.Click Apply.Click Save.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to try this method? (You can mute the sound if it bothers you.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGhiNakRx6Q

If you don't like that approach:

Forms: Try selecting the form control, then use the right properties panel to click on edit fields. The lookup column should be listed in the area with the checkboxes. If it is a brand new lookup column that you recently added to SharePoint, then try saving and closing your app, then reopening to force a hard refresh of the data.

Galleries: Click on the label control where you want the lookup, then use the formula bar TEXT property and use the formula ThisItem. followed by the field name then followed by another . (dot) then Value.

Comment: I can see my lookup fields if I start with sharepoint data however if I start with blank canvas I cannot see the lookup fields. I want the tablet layout the reason why I start from the blank canvas.

Comment: Hopefully someone from powerapps team can answer if this is not currently possible with blank canvas. Then landscape would be the only workaround.

Comment: Hi @audrie do you know how to get in touch with PowerApps team that can answer this question and [the other] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381243/is-powerapps-add-attachments-on-edit-form-available-in-sharepoint-on-prem-list). is it correct that you are also from Microsoft?