# Is powerapps add attachments on edit form available in Sharepoint on prem list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerapps

below is the [blog post](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/add-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists) detailing the feature but I cannot see it even after following the step to disable and re-enable attachments. I am using Sharepoint on premise list and a gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Sharepoint OnPrem 2013 and 2016 do not have support for attachments so you will not be able to use this feature.